# Comparing elements in two lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two  `lists`. Say one is `[6,4,2,1]` and the other is `[1,3,5,7]`. I need to  compare elements of respective positions (first element of first list compared with first element of second list). I need a third `list` such that it tells how many elements in first list are greater than elements of second list.For example when the above two lists are compared,the third list should be like `[2]` ( because `6 > 1` and `4 > 3`). How can I do this

Comment: Why do you wrap the result in a list? Why `[2]` instead of just `2` or e.g. `[1,1,0,0]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `zip(..)` and a *generator*:

```
list3 = [sum(x > y for x,y in zip(list1,list2))]
```

`sum(..)` sums over the elements and since `int(True)` is `1` and `int(False)` is `0`, it thus counts the number of pairs `x,y` where `x > y`.

You can boost performance a bit by using *list comprehension*:

```
list3 = [sum([x > y for x,y in zip(list1,list2)])]
```

But I do not really see why you construct a list, a simple integer is enough.

Comment: Summing over booleans, never really liked that.

Comment: @Elmex80s: well usually that works faster because you do not branch.

Comment: Interesting you mention this. Might raise the need for `count_true` and `count_false` functions for Python.

Comment: @Elmex80s: but the idea of Python is usually to provide a limited but very generic amount of builtins that can operate on a large set of queries.

Comment: Well, those functions might been put into a (new) module. Maybe the collections module would be the right place. edit: it is already there. `.count(True)`

Comment: @Elmex80s: but they are completely redundant. That's - in my opinion - one of the strong aspects of higher programs that allow higher order programming: you can use functions for a high variety of tasks...

Comment: I just edited my post because I found out it is already there. You can not apply it to generators I must admit.